# List of class instances in JS via static variable

Tags: javascript, static, ecmascript-6

I am trying to emulate the following class in js. This is Python, but I hope the intent is clear. I wish to have a static variable that contains a reference to every instance of the class. Thus I want to add every instance to the variable during construction.

```
class Foo:
    allFoos = [] # static variable

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        allFoos.append(self)
```

I am using ES6 classes (see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)) and haven't been able to manage this. What is the js analogue of the code above?

Comment: I don't know Phyton but if `allFoos` is a static variable it make no sense to assign some values to it in the constructor.

Comment: What are you intending to use this for? Generally this pattern isn't something you'd run across because it will leak memory because every single instance is referenced forever.

Comment: @loganfsmyth You are making a good point. Currently I am planning to keep the instances as long as my document is active, but that might change.

Comment: @Hosar The variable allFoos should contain a list of all instances of the class. We add an instance to the list when it is created, inside its constructor. I feel this makes a sufficient amount of sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo {
    constructor(){
        Foo.instances.push(this);
    }
}
Foo.instances = [];
```

Comment: FYI `static instances = [];` is not ES6, which the question was tagged with.

Comment: Hey, but can you point me in the direction the question was asked then? Just for my sake

Comment: You can assign a property to `Foo` just fine, it's just that assigning properties inside a class body is still a proposed syntax. You could just do `Foo.instances = [];` after the class declaration instead for instance. Your answer is using https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields which is just a proposal.

Comment: I cannot get this code to work in my application, I get an error `bad method definition` for the second line (latest release version firefox).

I am personally not particularly interested in ES6, but in compatible code. I've written all my code according to the doc I linked, so I want to keep it consistent and the necessary changes to a minimum.

Comment: `super()` needs to be called before `this` is accessed.

Comment: Isn't super necessary only if I am extending another class?

Answer (score 0):

May be this can fit :

```
class Foo {
   constructor() {
      Foo.allFoos = Foo.allFoos || [];
      Foo.allFoos.push(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: `super()` needs to be called before `this` is accessed.